# How to quickly edit determinate part of code inside different similar lines

Tags: vim, editor, editing

I have this problem I'm  adjusting a code I've made I have a structure  like this:

```
Apple1 = Fruit("ss","ss",[0.1,0.4],'w')
PineApple = Fruit("ss","ss",[0.315,0.4],'w')
Banana = Fruit("ss","ss",[0.315,0.280],'w')
...
...
```

Instead of `"ss"`I would like to type further information like `"Golden Delicious"`. For the moment I'm simply deleting `"ss"`clicking over it and then replacing it with the information I want to insert. I'm sure there is a faster way to do it, I've tried something with VIM macros but I can't figure out how to "Raw input" my data.
I've try simply to substitute it with Spyder, but is slow because I have to click substitute every time, with VIM for what I've try is the same.
Then I wonder how insert something else after `'w'`...
This is an example of an final output only to understand better the question :

```
  Apple1 = Fruit("Golden Delicous","red",[0.1,0.4],'w')
  PineApple = Fruit("Ananas comosus","green",[0.315,0.4],'w')
  Banana = Fruit(" Cavendish banana","yellow",[0.315,0.280],'w')
  ...
  ...
```

I reformulate the question: which is the faster way to change `"ss"`, for the moment I'm clicking over "`ss`" delate "ss" and write e.g "Golden Delicous" but is very slow. What I would like is that for **every single** `ss` the editor ask me to insert something to replace the single `ss`.

e.g. first `ss`in the fist line: I want to replace it typing something else  e.g. "Golden Delicous" second `ss`in the first line I want to replace it typing somethingelse e.g. `red`. First `ss`in the second line I want to replace it with s.e. e.g. `Ananas comosus`second `ss`in the second line I want to replace with s.e. e.g. `green` and so on.

I'm sure there is an answer for this somewhere but I can't find it!
Please if you down vote explain me why so I can improve it!

Comment: Have you tried `:%s/ss/Golden Delicious/g` in vim?

Comment: @thefourtheye This substitute all the "ss" with  "Golden Delicious" so the Banana is  a "Golden Delicous" too! Thanks however!

Comment: Banana doesnt even have a single s...

Comment: I don't understand your question very well. It's not clear which instances of "ss" you do want to replace, and which ones you don't. Please clarify. Do you mean you want the editor to just locate every "ss" occurrence, and for each of them let you directy type something to replace it? Is it that what you want?

Comment: From what it seems, you will have to write a script to solve this. I don't see why it will be difficult to do this in python.

Comment: @thefourtheye No, please read the edited question thanks

Comment: @eleom is a question about editing simply I want to write instead "ss" something else with an editor

Comment: @axiom I'm searching for the best practice to do it with an editor write a script to edit another script is not the best thing to do I prefer to use it only if I have no alternatives!

Comment: @GM: In your input data example you have two instances of `ss` for each line and you didn't tell us anything about the second one. Do you want to replace only the first one? Do you want to leave the second one as is? What are those `red`, `green` and `yellow`? Or will you tell new requirements after you get the first answer? Please, clarify all this points.

Comment: @Birei Try to read the edited question or the gits answer... Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

As far as I understand, the data that you want to substitute for "ss" does not have regular structure, so you will need to enter it by hand.

In Vim you would do it like this:

1. Place the cursor over the first "ss", then press `*` and then `N`.
2. Press `ce`, enter the new data (e.g. "Golden Delicious"), then leave Insert mode by pressing Escape.
3. Press `n` to jump to the next instance of "ss".

Repeat steps 2 and 3 ad libitum.

Look up [`:h *`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/pattern.html#star) and [`:h n`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/pattern.html#n) for more information.

Comment: You can record those steps in a register and do `999@@` or whatever big number to replace all of them at the same time.

Comment: +1 but I would replace step 1 with `/ss<cr>` so to not leave the home row.

Comment: @Birei - the replacements differ each time. (afaik) A macro doesn't stop to ask for input.

Comment: +1 This do what I want! Thank a lot! I hope something more automated but for now is the best solution!

Answer (score 3):

I would do it like that:

```
:%s/ss/\=input('Replacement: ')/gc
```

This queries you for each occurrence. With the `/c` flag, the display is even updated during the loop (at the cost of having to additionally answer `y` for each occurrence); without the flag, you would need to keep track of where you are yourself.

Comment: +1 thanks this is the best answer for the moment I've found a 2 steps solution  with spyder see [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=urMXHljlTl8&feature=youtu.be) but I think in VIM your solution is the more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a function that searches the whole file substituting all `"ss"` strings with values from arrays populated with the replacement data:

```
function! ChangeSS()
    let ss1 = ['Golden Delicous', 'Ananas comosus', 'Cavendish banana']
    let ss2 = ['red', 'green', 'yellow']

    call cursor(1, 1)
    let l = "ss2"
    while search('"ss"', 'W') > 0 
        if l == "ss1"
            let l = "ss2"
        else
            let l = "ss1"
        endif
        execute 'normal ci"' . remove({l}, 0)
    endwhile
endfunction
```

It uses a reference variable (`l`) that exchanges which array you want to extract data from. `ss1` is for first appearance of `"ss"` in the line and `ss2` for the second one.

Run it like:

```
:call ChangeSS()
```

That (in my test) yields:

```
Apple1 = Fruit("Golden Delicous","red",[0.1,0.4],'w')
PineApple = Fruit("Ananas comosus","green",[0.315,0.4],'w')
Banana = Fruit("Cavendish banana","yellow",[0.315,0.280],'w')
```

Comment: Thanks this works great! My only problem is that I have to see the context (e.g. name of the "fruit") to understand what information insert! Maybe I can take a copy of the file open in another window to scroll down it when I compile the ss1 and ss2 lists. Thanks!

Comment: @GM: But what you want to achieve doesn't follow any guideline and it's very arbitrary. Computers are not yet intelligent enough to read your brain, sorry. This is my best approach to your problem.

Comment: Please don't feel upset I'm only searching to solve a problem that occurred to me in the best way. I'm sure is not so arbitrary as it seems. I hoped voting up your answer was enough to testimony how I appreciate your help!

Comment: @GM: Of course I didn't feel upset, but to automate a process you need an algorithm that makes all steps clear. And your problem doesn't. Each line has a different replacement string (we don't know them in advance) and depends in other context we neither know in advance. You cannot do a program like that, you will have to do it by hand like **glts's** suggestion. To let a computer do it you have to tell it how.

Comment: I'm sorry maybe my question wasn't so clear I'm not a native english speaker however I found what I want to do using spyder cmd+F and pressing F3 I've post a video to show you  http://youtu.be/urMXHljlTl8 Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: @GM: Thanks for the video. I see at the end you did it by hand. I hope you didn't spend many hours like that :-)